# How to get cart info using user_id or mail_id in magento custom coding?

Tags: magento-1.9, array

I try  user_id throw get cart detail my code is below but get o/p only array() not display array value give me suggestion

```
error_reporting(0);
include("../app/Mage.php");
umask(0); 
// Initialize Magento
Mage::app();
$user_id=$_POST['user_id']."1";
$customerData = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($user_id);
//print_r($customerData);
//echo $customerData->getId();
$customer_email=$customerData->getEmail();
$customer_detail = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
$customer_detail->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$customer_detail->loadByEmail($customer_email);
$storeIds = Mage::app()->getWebsite(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId())->getStoreIds();
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setSharedStoreIds($storeIds)->loadByCustomer($customer_detail);
if ($quote) {

$productsResult = array();
foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) { 

   echo  $product = $item->getProduct(); 
    $productsResult[] = array(// Basic product data
        'product_id' => $product->getId(),
        'sku' => $product->getSku(),
        'name' => $product->getName(),
        'set' => $product->getAttributeSetId(),
        'type' => $product->getTypeId(),
        'category_ids' => $product->getCategoryIds(),
        'website_ids' => $product->getWebsiteIds()
    );
}
print_r($productsResult);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
 <?php
        require_once('app/Mage.php');
        umask(0);
        Mage::app();

        $customerId = 1; // your customer ID
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);

        $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
            ->setSharedStoreIds($storeIds)
            ->loadByCustomer($customer);

        if ($quote) {
            $collection = $quote->getItemsCollection();
            if ($collection->count() > 0) {
                foreach( $collection as $item ) {
                    echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
                    echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
                    echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
                    echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
                    echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
                    echo "<br />";

                }
            }
        }

?>
```

This will get you all quotes ever for this customer.